# Javascript - How to get star rating from object array field rating?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, font-awesome

I have this object array:

```
var test_data = [    
                {
                    "id" : "Test01", //Has to be a string form ID
                    "test_info"  : "This is the test information",
                    "test_rating" : 5
                },
                {
                    "id" : "Test02", //Has to be a string form ID
                    "test_info"  : "This is the test information",
                    "test_rating" : 2
                }
```

As it stands I am using the following to populate a unordered list (but it is only populating the id)

```
fieldOutputId.forEach(function(id) {
    $("#idList").append('<li><a href="#">' + id +" "+ "</a></li>"); 
});
```

I am wondering how to get Stars appearing to the right with the value of `test_rating` that's stored in `fieldOutputRating` like showing up like this picture (Stars being the red text)

Fig1 :[image: Star Rating]

**-----EDIT-----**

Thanks to @ChrisG this gets it inline, id & test_rating:

```
test_data.forEach(function(item) { $("#idList").append('<li><a href="#">' + item.id+ '</a><div class="fa fa-star">'+ item.test_rating+ "</div></li>"); })
```

With the above code I am trying to get the stars to appear in-line (done) and as stars using font-awesome library with a `class="fa fa-star`

This is what the above is giving:

[image: Not Working Star Rating]

So its getting the test_rating but not giving any stars for it. 
Any help is appreciated??

Comment: How about `test_data.forEach(function (item) { ... });`? Now simply use `item.id` and `item.test_rating` in your function. (if you're wondering how to get the index, it is passed as second param to your callback)

Comment: @ChrisG yeah thats got them perfectly beside each other :-) As number though

Comment: So is your actual question how to turn a number into a bunch of stars? How about a loop?

Comment: Yes but from within `test_data.forEach(function(item) {
  $("#idList").append('<li><a href="#">' + item.id+ '</a><div class="fa fa-star">'+ item.test_rating+ "</div></li>");
 })` How would I do that? the rating results shown as stars like in the picture above? Using the font-awesome with a `class="fa fa-star`

Comment: Did you take a look at [ic3b3rg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53752879/5734311)? My take: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/84py2dLg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build up the 'star rating' from the input, like below:

```
test_data.forEach(function(data) {
    let rating_str = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < data.rating; i++) rating_str += '*';
    $("#idList").append('<li><a href="#">' + data.id +" "+ "</a><span>" + rating_str + "</span></li>"); 
});
```

If your 'star' is some image, instead of just '*' like in my code example, you can do `rating_str += '<img src="..." />'`

Comment: You know of how to do it while using the font-awesome library? Like as you've done here which is great, but to use the font-awesome to get them appearing as stars like in the image above

Comment: Do `rating_str += '<span class="fas fa-star"></span>'` inside the for loop above

Comment: `test_data.forEach(function(data) {
  const rating_str = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < data.rating; i++) rating_str += '<span class="fas fa-star"></span>';
  $("#idList").append('<li><a href="#">' + data.id +" "+ "</a><span>" + rating_str + "</span></li>"); 
 });` I assume you mean like this? and that just gives this "Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable."

Comment: you need to replace `const` with `var` (and learn to read and understand error messages)

Comment: Oh yeah, missed that I was re-assigning to a const. Edited the code in my solution

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```js
const test_data = [    
  {
    "id" : "Test01",
    "test_info"  : "This is the test information",
    "test_rating" : 5
  },
  {
    "id" : "Test02",
    "test_info"  : "This is the test information",
    "test_rating" : 2
  }
];

test_data.forEach(({id, test_rating}) => {
  $("#idList").append(`<li><a href="#">${id}</a> ${'*'.repeat(test_rating)}</li>`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="idList" />
```